# Opencart - Вывод отображения статусов без "Нет в наличии" в категорию

Tags: opencart

Всем привет. Голова кипит :(, прошу помощи.

Хочу вывести отображение статусов в категорию под ценой, но чтобы там не отображался статус "нет в наличии" для товаров с менее одного и более остатком на складе.

Что делал:

1. В контроллер category.php

После:

```
$data['products'][] = array(
```

Добавил:

```
'quantity'       => $result['quantity'],
'stock_text'     => $result['stock_status'],
```

2. В контроллере `product.php`

После:

```
product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
```

Добавил:

```
quantity' => $result['quantity'], 
'stock_text' => $result['stock_status'],
```

Перед:

```
if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
```

Добавил:

```
$data['stock_quantity'] = $product_info['quantity'];
$data['stock_text'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
```

2. В шаблон "category.twig" добавляю "product.stock_text".

Статусы выводит, но показывает их все, что есть, без фильтра, т.е вместе с "нет в наличии". Подскажите пожалуйста что нужно добавить/изменить?
Может как то нужно задать id статуса, чтобы он не выводился и обернуть им product.stock_text ?

[image: Изображение результата]

Comment: добавьте в вопрос листинг участка category.php, где вы внедряете условие

Comment: @KirillKorushkin, добавил.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin подскажите пожалуйста что нужно добавить в $data['products'] ?

Answer (score 0):

Управляйте отображением статусов из админки. В **настройках** вкладка **опции**, в ней находите блок **склад**.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройте как на картинке.

Конкретно про вашему примеру:

```
category.twig >

{% if product.quantity > 1 %}
    {{ product.stock_text }}
{% endif %}
```

Так должно работать.

**UPD:**
Не выводить только определённый статус:

Находите в базе в таблице **stock_status** id целевого статуса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляете его в **`$data['products'][]`** и проверяете при выводе

```
{% if stock_status_id != 5 %}
    {{ product.stock_text }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Кирилл, спасибо за ответ, но это к сожалению не то. Хочу вывести показ всех статусов под ценой в категории. В моём первом сообщении метод работает, но показывает все статусы без исключения, мне же нужно убрать "Нет в наличии", чтобы этот статус не показывался в никаких случаях(больше или меньше нуля). Этот статус у меня работает на кнопке корзины.
Фото: https://s6.postimg.org/aekckh95d/Screenshot-2018-3-21_Desktops.png

Comment: Я так делал, Кирилл. Статус 'нет в наличии' не выводится только на тех товарах, где нулевое количество. Это не совсем то, чего нужно достичь. Нужно скрыть конкретный ID статус - нет в наличии. При таком условии "product.quantity > 1" скрываются все статусы на продуктах с нулевым количеством. Нужно убрать только "нет в наличии". Все остальные статусы должны показываться и не важно какое у него количество на складе.

Comment: Спасибо, Кирилл, но я как раз кручусь примерно вокруг этих строчек "stock_status_id != 5" и не понимаю как добавить его в "$data['products']". Остался последний шаг, но не могу его выполнить :( Соображайка не работает(